# Gradle - how to create an ear file

Tags: ear, gradle

I am new to Gradle, How to create a ear file using Gradle? It will have , including set of java projects and web project (war file). Java project will have set of compling resources. Web project will have a set of jar files with web.xml.
Please suggest the best way to build t his ear file using Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ear-plugin is a part of 1.0-milestone-4 which is downloadable from here http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/gradle-snapshots/ . You can also build the latest version from source. The distribution image contain documentation for the plugin.

Comment: 1.0-milestone-4 just got [released](http://wiki.gradle.org/display/GRADLE/Gradle+1.0-milestone-4+Release+Notes). The [documentation for the EAR plugin](http://gradle.org/releases/1.0-milestone-4/docs/userguide/ear_plugin.html) is available as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it created ear file. I am trying to include war file after building from sub directory 'wars/myweb' I get this erro message **Project with path 'wars/myweb' could not be found in root project 'trunk'** @Benjamin Muschko

Comment: Thanks for the help, it created ear file. I am trying to include war file after building from sub directory 'wars/myweb' I get this erro message Project with path 'wars/myweb' could not be found in root project 'trunk' @BenjaminM

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle file; and your project structure?@

Comment: Not able to add my gradle build file, as there are restriction of characters, any suggestion?

Comment: I figured it out, settings file was missing with include. Now it works. Thanks for your help